# Understand the behavior of `super.__init__()` with dynamic value in parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am using python 3.8 (same behavior in 3.9) and I have the below parent class (simplified to illustrate the example) where `date` is dynamically set when instantiating the class.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time

class Parent():
    def __init__(self, date=datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()):
        self.date = date

    def date_id(self):
        return id(self.date)
```

instantiating a child class as below returns 10 times the same id for the variable `self.date`. My assumption was that on instantiating a new `Child` class it will create a new `self.date` variable.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(Child().date_id())
```

If I want to achieve the expected behavior I instead need to define my dynamic assignment in the `__init__` body as such

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

what is the mechanism in python that results in this behavior?

Comment: @matszwecja does it mean when the interpreter parses the code?

Comment: Your default argument is only evaluated once at class definition time. Not every time you call `__init__`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @matszwecja if you post the answer I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Btw, this has nothing to do with inheritance. The same would happen for 10 instances of `Parent`

Comment: @Teddy I'm not sure what you mean by "when the interpreter parses the code". Which process are you referring to?

Comment: @matszwecja I was referring to this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html. though I found that it is evaluated when it is actually called. ☺️

Comment: @Teddy Well, lexical analysis is concerned about structure. It will never have anything to do with any actual evaluation of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the defining scope"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) (...) **Important warning: The default value is evaluated only once.**

Example from the docs:

```
i = 5

def f(arg=i):
    print(arg)

i = 6
f()
```

will print `5`